# In Sublime Text, can I Find and Replace a variable value?

Tags: regex, sublimetext, sublimetext4

I'm using the latest version of Sublime text and I would like to Find & Replace a variable value in my list of URLs.

So an example of the URLs in the list is;

`root/tesco-loves-baby-bath-and-room-thermometer_w227_h218.jpg`

and

`toddler-lunch-ideas-dairy-free_w555_h555.jpg`

And I need to replace this URL with;

`.jpg?q=80&auto=format&w=1800&ar=16:9&fit=crop&crop=top`

However, instead of the **w=1800** in this replacement, I need to extract out the `_w` value of the original URL, and use this in the new URL.

So the

`_w227_h218.jpg`

part of the original URL would be replaced with;

`.jpg?q=80&auto=format&w=227&ar=16:9&fit=crop&crop=top`

And

`_w555_h555.jpg`

would be replaced with;

`.jpg?q=80&auto=format&w=555&ar=16:9&fit=crop&crop=top`

etc.

Is this possible in Sublime text?

Or is there another way of doing this?

I did think of trying to use regex, but my experience of using regex is very limited so thought I'd give this a go first.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This is actually quite straightforward to do. In Sublime, select **`Find → Replace…`**. Make sure the Regular Expression option is selected. In the `Find:` box, enter:

```
_w(\d+)_h\d+.jpg
```

The parentheses `()` indicate a capturing group. `\d+` searches for one or more digits.

Now, in the `Replace:` box, enter this:

```
\.jpg?q=80&auto=format&w=$1&ar=16:9&fit=crop&crop=top
```

The `$1` means *insert first capture group here*. Hit the <kbd>Replace</kbd> button a few times to make sure your URLs are being changed properly. Once you're satisfied it works, you can hit <kbd>Replace All</kbd> to make the changes all at once.

I've put a [demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/g1SPyX/1) so you can see the exact breakdown of what's going on.